# Is there a way to intercept and modify packet

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to create a program that would change the ip header of packets sent to a specific host. To do this, I intercept packets using libtins.

Here is my `capture.hpp` file

```
#pragma once

#include <tins/tins.h>
using namespace Tins;

namespace capturing {

    bool capture (PDU &pdu);

}
```

this is my `capture.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "headers/capturing.hpp"
#include <tins/tins.h>

using namespace Tins;
using namespace std;

namespace capturing {

    bool capture (PDU &pdu) {

        IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>();
        // ip.src_addr("127.0.0.1");

        cout << ip.src_addr() << endl;
        cout << ip.dst_addr() << endl;
        cout << ip.id() << endl;

        return false;

    }

}
```

I tried working with pointers to pdu and IP, but it didn’t work, the packet sent didn’t change. Just no ideas about it.

Comment: Unless this machine is responsible for *forwarding* the packet, the answer is effectively "no". If you're the NAT, you can do whatever you want, though doing it in user-mode code is going to be a gigantic mess. This is what a kernel driver is for.

Comment: Right.  You can capture and inspect packets, and you can send new packets, but you can't interfere with the packet you sniffed.

Comment: Maybe I can "cancel" the sending of packets in order to generate my own based on them and send them? Or is the proxy the only option?

Comment: While the questions you're asking are fine, everyone needs to learn, it's also a sign you're in way, way over your head here and need to invest time in understanding how the various [OSI layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) function and where they fit in to this particular problem. Learn about Ethernet. Learn about IP and TCP. Most importantly, learn about the difference between *packet capture* (sniffing) and *packet rewriting* (NAT/proxying).